# what is <acl> tag in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml, acl

```
<acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <Brain_Vire>
                        <title>Vire Module</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    </Brain_Vire>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
</acl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stands for Access Control Lists - allowing access to modules.

See more here: http://alanstorm.com/magento_acl_authentication